# Query to get term id using post id?

Tags: terms

I know there is connection between post table with term table but I am unable to figure it out.

`wp_terms`, `wp_termmeta`, `wp_term_relationships` & `wp_term_taxonomy` relation is a little confusing. So, I am unable to write a query to get term id from post id.

**Actual Problem:**

I am using this piece of code to get an object and extract term id from that. But for some reasons, it is not working so I want to manually query in database to pull the term id and do rest of process.

```
get_metadata_by_mid('post', $id);
```

it returns this object: (**on local machine**)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta_id] => 1268   //this id is passed to function like get_metadata_by_mid('post', 1268);
    [post_id] => 222    //want to obtain this ID
    [meta_key] => _menu_item_url
    [meta_value] => 
)
```

Returns no result (**on server**) [so looking for alternative way]

**NOTE:**

- `get_metadata_by_mid` works on local machine but doesn't work on live (i don't know, why whereas I have same version in both environment)
- If someone can provide alternative way then it would be better than manual query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good practice to use query when you have already builtin functions but for your need.

**Try this solution**:

```
global $wpdb;
$meta = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`  WHERE `meta_id` = $id" );

//will return same object like returned by get_metadata_by_mid() function
print_r($meta);
```

**Debugging Technique:**

As you mentioned, `get_metadata_by_mid()` isn't working on live server. I would say,

1. Select any post id (for testing)
2. Login to `phpmyadmin`
3. Run this search query

   ```
   SELECT *  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_id` = ID_GOES_HERE
   //copy post_id from the results
   ```
4. Run this query

   ```
   SELECT *  FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id` = POST_ID_GOES_HERE
   ```

Try to match the process on both (local & live) server. Hopefully, it will help you identify problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The debugging technique is very useful, the postmeta table was empty for that specific id on live server. So I added new product and there was no entry created for new product in postmeta table on live and local machine. I don't know, why. Any debugging technique for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

It seems you are trying to get the terms associated to a post, but the function get_metadata_by_mid gets Metadata.

If you are indeed trying to get all terms associated to a specific post, you can use the function [wp_get_object_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) or [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

If you are trying to do something else, please restate your question to better explain what the intended result is ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer, and to be honest if I do know how `get_metadata_by_mid` works then I could rewrite my own query. What I need is `term_id` of associated post and it returns correct object when I use this code `get_metadata_by_mid('post', $id);` but it doesn't work on live server so I am looking for alternative way like querying db.

Answer (score 0):

the relationship of post and term you want is in table `wp_term_relasionship`.
The object id equal with `post_id`
So you can write your own query to access that

Comment: returns an empty array, i think it's relationship will be in some meta table but I don't know

Comment: could you try this select t.term_id, t.name from wp_posts p inner join wp_term_relationships tr on p.ID = tr.object_id
      inner join wp_terms t on tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
where p.ID = $id